# for loop data , iteration and some statistic calculations in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've for loop which gives me energy values. I would like to know how I can perform the following tasks within for loop;

```
for i in range(1, 1000): 
    system = moves.move(system, 50, true)
    print("%d: %s" % (i, system.energies()))
```

1- How I can store the output energy values in a array or make a list. e.g. `[E1, E2, E3, E4, E5, ... E1000]`.

2- I want to take the mean of last 10 values of stored array `[E991, E992 ... E1000]`. I named this as calculated mean.

3- Now the program test the calculated mean (from step 2) and my set mean value in script like this

```
if calculated_mean <= set_mean
```

then the program continue to next.

but if the condition is not satisfied then the program run another 1000 steps which will be from 1001 to 2000 starting from 1000 as initial point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start = 0
calculated_mean = float('inf')
while calculated_mean > set_mean:
    energies = []
    for i in range(start, start + 1000): 
        system = moves.move(system, 50, true)
        energy = system.energies()
        energies.append(energy)
        print("%d: %s" % (i, energy))
    calculated_mean = sum(energies[-10:]) / 10
```

Comment: i got a problem with my calculated_mean line due to my energy output values. I posted on my wall here. Any clue for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Note: range(1, 1000) is inclusive on the left but not on the right, so your last value will be 999, and length of the list will be 999:

```py
>>> range(1,1000)[-1]
999
>>> len(range(1,1000))
999
```

Is this what you were asking how to do?

```py
def mean(vals):
    return (sum(vals)/len(vals))

set_mean = *your desired value*
calculated_mean = None
energy = []

while (calculated_mean is None) or (calculated_mean <= set_mean):
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        system = moves.move(system, 50, true)
        print("%d: %s" % (i, system.energies()))
        energy.append(system.energies())
    calculated_mean =  mean(energy[-10:])
```

Comment: it does not matter with 999 or 1000. I want to take mean of last 10 resultant energy values from loop. there are some suggestion already. I am tryint them now. I will back here if got some issue. I am very thank full to all my fellows for immediate response.

Comment: i got a problem with my calculated_mean line due to my energy output values. I posted on my wall here. Any clue for this ?